# Lattices in the complex plane

Tags: ring-theory, integer-lattices

Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. It is a lattice in the complex plane: the set of points with integer coordinates with respect to the basis: $1,\sqrt{2}i$. Each mesh of the lattice is a rectangle, with base parallel to the real axis of length $1$ and height of length $\sqrt{2}$.

Now consider $R=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}]$. My purpose is to figure out what is the shape of the lattice in this case, as i did in the previous case. I have $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}]=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, hence the generic element has the form 
$$\displaystyle\frac{a+b\sqrt{-3}}{2}$$
with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a=b\pmod{2}$. But i cannot see what kind of meshes i have, are they squares, rectangles, parallelograms or what?

Comment: Consider the fundamental mesh, with vertices $0,\, 1,\, \zeta,\, 1+\zeta$, where $\zeta = \frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. The meshes are parallelograms, rhomboids even. Well, you could take a different lattice basis, $(1,1+\zeta)$ for example, then the meshes would no longer be rhomboids. Still parallelograms, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ is a cube root of $-1$.  The fundamental parallelogram is a rhombus which is the union of two equilateral triangles, so
you have a "triangular lattice".

[image]

Comment: so, equilateral triangles of side 1. How could you deduce that so quickly from the fact that it is a cubic root of $-1$?

Comment: Multiplication by a cube root of $-1$ is a $60$ degree rotation of the complex plane, and thus of your lattice (after all, it is a ring so closed under multiplication).